# How to use Lottie animation library in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

we are using Magento V 2.3.5-p1.

According to the client's requirements, they want to display animation in some of the pages. for that, they gave us .json file for animation. we have used Lottie js to display animation on the website. For that I have uploaded `lottie-player.js` file in `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/web/js` directory and included this JS in `default_head_blocks.xml` file.

After including this JS file I am getting js error in browser's console and this error seems to be in all pages. Because this js error other default scripts are not working sometimes. please refer below screenshot for the error

[image]

This error is related to the "define()" function. So, my conclusion is that the "define()" function is already defined in Magento's default jquery. So when the `lottie-player.js` loads on the website it is conflicting with Magento's default jquery because this file also have it's own "define()" function.

Have anyone used the Lottie animation library in Magento 2? Can anyone give me any suggestions on how can I use Lottie animation js in Magento 2?

Comment: Have you added the JS via XML by any chance?

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my question I have added "lottie-player.js" file via XML(default_head_blocks.xml) file.

Comment: Ah my bad I skim read that and missed it. That is the issue, you need to load this through Require JS. I'll write up an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue when you load a file that supports Require JS via XML, the fix is to use Require JS to load your script.

1. Load your own custom JS file using your preferred method (XML, `x-magento-init`, `data-mage-init`)
2. Load Lottie inside this JS file like so:

```
define([
    "js/lottie-player"
], function (lottie) {
    'use strict';

    console.log(lottie);
});
```

You can then use `lottie` in your script, the console log above returns the below in the browser:

[image]

Comment: I have implemented your solution but I have made a small change. I have used "require" instead of "define" in the script which you gave me and now it seems to be working fine and there are no errors in the console. So, Is it ok to use require?

Comment: Yeah you are fine to use require. If this answer has solved the problem for you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I marked the answer as accepted. can you please look at my other question as well
https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319197/90803

Comment: I don't know the answer to that one sorry :(