# How to display product image in summary section in bundle product page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, bundled-product, x-magento-template

we are using Magento V 2.3.5-p1

In default Magento when we select options on the bundle product page the selected option will be displayed in the summary section. By default, only the quantity and name of the selected option are displayed in the summary section.

I have created one bundle product and created bundle options with input type radio buttons and added products in that bundle option. I have fetched and displayed product images (which were added as bundle options) on the front end.

what I want to do is display the product image with the product name when the user selects an option in the bundle product. I want to display images in the summary section.

I had noticed that the summary section is based on `x-Magento-template`. So How can I display product images in the summary section? Is there a way to display the product images in `x-Magento-template`?

Comment: Yes, you need to override the magentio default files and added your custom code there into your extension.

Answer (score 0):

so here I was facing same problem as yours after ages !!!
finally I solved it.

(1) Actually on summary.phtml file data is rendered using `this.cache.currentElement` All the Product data coming from it and it has Product name [label] & Price in itself.

(2) For Price we have to add `priceUtils` function in `product-summary.js`.

(3) For Product Image we have to **UpdateElement** of `this.cache.currentElement`.

So, let's Do it !!!

--> Find **summary.phtml** in your core files :
`vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml`

override in your custom module : `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml`

we have to modify & add some extra codes here in our custom file.

Step 1 : here we have to get Parent Product ID as well as based on that we have to get Child Product Data. for that I simply **Extend** Core Block of summary.phtml which is "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View".

Create **di.xml** for it like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" 
                type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Now Create Custom Block **VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product** View.php like this :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View as MagentoProductView;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class View extends MagentoProductView
{
    /**
     * Custom function to retrieve product data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomFunction(Product $product)
    {
        $parentId = $product->getTypeId();
        
        return $parentId; 
    }

    public function getProductData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $productData = [
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'sku' => $product->getSku(),
        ];
        return $productData;
    }
    
    public function getChildImagesByParentId($parentId)
    {
        $childData = [];
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        if ($product->getTypeId() === 'bundle') {
            $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance()->getOptionsIds($product),
                $product
            );
            foreach ($selectionCollection as $option) {
                if ($option['parent_product_id'] == $product->getId()) {
                    $ChildName = $option->getName();
                    $childProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($option->getProductId());
                    $childImage = $childProduct->getImage();
                    $childImage = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $childImage;
                    $childData[] = [
                        'name' => $ChildName,
                        'image' => $childImage,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        return $childData;
    }
}
```

Step 2 : Custom **summary.phtml** as below :

```
<?php
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$ParentSku = $block->getCustomFunction($_product);
$ChildData = $block->getChildImagesByParentId($ParentSku);
?>


<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $block->hasOptions()) : ?>
<div id="bundleSummary"
     class="block-bundle-summary"
     data-mage-init='{"sticky":{"container": ".product-add-form"}}'>
    <div class="title">
        <strong><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Your Customization')) ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="bundle-info">
            <?= $block->getImage($_product, 'bundled_product_customization_page')->toHtml() ?>
            <div class="product-details">
                <strong class="product name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?></strong>
                <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                    <p class="available stock" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                    </p>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <p class="unavailable stock" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Availability')) ?>">
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                    </p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('product.price.render.bundle.customization', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="bundle-summary">
            <strong class="subtitle"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Summary')) ?></strong>
            <div id="bundle-summary" data-container="product-summary">
                <ul data-mage-init='{"productSummary": []}' class="bundle items"></ul>
                <script data-template="bundle-summary" type="text/x-magento-template">
                    <li>
                        <strong class="label"><%- data._label_ %>:</strong>
                        <div data-container="options">
                            <% _.each(data._selected_options_, function(option) { %>
                                <div>
                                    <%= option.label %>
                                    <span class="option-price">+ <%= option.price %></span>
                                </div>
                            <% }); %>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </script>
                <script data-template="bundle-option" type="text/x-magento-template">
                    <div class="child-image">
                        <% _.each(childData, function(item) { %>
                            <% if (item.name === data._label_) { %>
                                <img src="<%= item.image %>" alt="<%= item.name %>" class="bundle-image">
                            <% } %>
                        <% }); %>
                    </div>
                    <div><?= /* @noEscape */ __('%1 x %2', '<%- data._quantity_ %>', '<%- data._label_ %>') ?></div>
                    <div class="total_price"><%- data._option_total_ %></div>
                    
                </script>
               
            </div>
        </div>

        <?= $block->getChildHtml('addtocart', true) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .child-image {
    width: 20% !important;
    margin-top: 15px !important;
}
</style>
<script>
    var childData = <?php echo json_encode($ChildData); ?>;
</script>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        ".product-add-form": {
            "slide": {
                "slideSpeed": 1500,
                "slideSelector": "#bundle-slide",
                "slideBackSelector": ".action.customization.back",
                "bundleProductSelector": "#bundleProduct",
                "bundleOptionsContainer": ".product-add-form"
                <?php if ($block->isStartCustomization()) : ?>
                ,"autostart": true
                <?php endif;?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now template file looking Perfect!!!
We have to move on **product-summary.js** for render Extra Elements of our [ProductPrice,Product Images,etc]

so go to this path : `vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary.js`
Now we have to ovveride this js file and for that we have to create `requirejs-config.js`.
Create `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` like this :

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Bundle/js/product-summary': 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/product-summary-override'
        }
    }
};
```

Now **last but not least** we have to create `product-summary-override.js` on this path :  `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary-override.js` like this :

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'priceUtils', // add here priceUtils as dependency to format price
    'jquery/ui',
    'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle'
], function ($, mageTemplate, priceUtils) { // add priceUtils as paramater
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Widget product Summary:
     * Handles rendering of Bundle options and displays them in the Summary box
     */
    $.widget('mage.productSummary', {
        options: {
            mainContainer:          '#product_addtocart_form',
            templates: {
                summaryBlock:       '[data-template="bundle-summary"]',
                optionBlock:        '[data-template="bundle-option"]',
                image:              '[data-template="bundle-image"]'
            },
            optionSelector:         '[data-container="options"]',
            summaryContainer:       '[data-container="product-summary"]',
            bundleSummaryContainer: '.bundle-summary'
        },
        cache: {},
        /**
         * Method attaches event observer to the product form
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            this.element
                .closest(this.options.mainContainer)
                .on('updateProductSummary', $.proxy(this._renderSummaryBox, this))
                .priceBundle({})
            ;
        },
        /**
         * Method extracts data from the event and renders Summary box
         * using jQuery template mechanism
         * @param {Event} event
         * @param {Object} data
         * @private
         */
        _renderSummaryBox: function (event, data) {
            this.cache.currentElement = data.config;
            this.cache.currentElementCount = 0;

            // Clear Summary box
            this.element.html('');

            $.each(this.cache.currentElement.selected, $.proxy(this._renderOption, this));
            this.element
                .parents(this.options.bundleSummaryContainer)
                .toggleClass('empty', !this.cache.currentElementCount); // Zero elements equal '.empty' container
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} key
         * @param {String} row
         * @private
         */
        _renderOption: function (key, row) {
            var template;

            if (row && row.length > 0 && row[0] !== null) {

                var basePrice = 0;

              // start calculate option total price
                var widget = this;
                row.forEach(function(item){
                    var selection = widget.cache.currentElement.options[key].selections[item];
                    basePrice += selection.prices.finalPrice.amount; // add the base price of each selected option
                });
                    this.cache.currentElement.options[key].basePrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(basePrice, this.cache.currentElement.priceFormat.pattern);

                template = this.element
                    .closest(this.options.summaryContainer)
                    .find(this.options.templates.summaryBlock)
                    .html();
                template = mageTemplate($.trim(template), {
                    data: {
                        _label_: this.cache.currentElement.options[key].title,
                        _option_total_: this.cache.currentElement.options[key].basePrice
                    }
                });
                

                this.cache.currentKey = key;
                this.cache.summaryContainer = $(template);
                this.element.append(this.cache.summaryContainer);

                $.each(row, function(index, item) {
                var option = widget.cache.currentElement.options[key].selections[item];
                option.basePrice = priceUtils.formatPrice(option.prices.finalPrice.amount, widget.cache.currentElement.priceFormat.pattern); // save base price in option object
                option.labelWithBasePrice = option.label + ' + ' + option.basePrice; // add base price to the label
                widget._renderOptionRow(index, item);
        }); 
                this.cache.currentElementCount += row.length;

                //Reset Cache
                this.cache.currentKey = null;
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param {String} key
         * @param {String} optionIndex
         * @private
         */
        _renderOptionRow: function (key, optionIndex) {
            var template;

            template = this.element
                .closest(this.options.summaryContainer)
                .find(this.options.templates.optionBlock)
                .html();
            template = mageTemplate($.trim(template), {
                data: {
                    _quantity_: this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].qty,
                    _label_: this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].name,
                    _option_total_: priceUtils.formatPrice(this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].prices.finalPrice.amount * this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].qty, this.cache.currentElement.priceFormat.pattern) // row price calculation
                }
            });
            this.cache.summaryContainer
                .find(this.options.optionSelector)
                .append(template);
        },
        updateElement: function(element) {
            var $element = $(element),
                optionId = $element.attr('data-option-id'),
                optionValue = $element.attr('data-option-value'),
                optionQty = $element.attr('data-option-qty'),
                optionPrice = $element.attr('data-option-price'),
                optionLabel = $element.parents('.product-options-wrapper').find('.product-options-label[for="' + optionId + '"]').text(),
                imageSrc = $element.parents('.bundle-option').find('.bundle-image').attr('src'); // Get the image src from the DOM
                console.log("imageSrc",imageSrc);
            this.cache.currentElement = {
                id: optionId,
                value: optionValue,
                qty: optionQty,
                price: optionPrice,
                label: optionLabel,
                image: imageSrc // Add the image src to the current element
            };
            this.cache.selectedOptions[optionId] = {
                value: optionValue,
                qty: optionQty,
                price: optionPrice,
                label: optionLabel,
                image: imageSrc // Add the image src to the selected options
            };
        }

    });

    return $.mage.productSummary;
});
```

Code Part Completed !!!

Now Run all the Required cmd commands and show frontend :

**Before :**
[image]

**After :**
[image]

***Just Understand my Steps Carefully and ping me if you got any trouble !!!***
***Happy To Help you***